# Live action TV show about normal siblings who go to a monster high school

Tags: story-identification, tv, vampire, zombie, werewolf

There was this live action show I watched in I think the early 2010’s, and it was about two normal siblings, an older sister and younger brother who move house/school and the new school is a monster school, the boys best friend is a Frankenstein/zombie and the girls love interest is a werewolf. Also I’m pretty sure the new house they live in is owned by a sentient brain in a jar.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is ***[Summer in Transylvania](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1761870/)*** (2010–2011).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_in_Transylvania):

> *Summer in Transylvania* is a live action children's television programme which aired on Nickelodeon. The programme, originally called *Freaky Farleys*, was renamed *Summer in Transylvania* and was filmed in Hendon, London. It is Nickelodeon UK's first original TV series since *Genie in the House*. It was announced on 23 June 2012 that the programme would not return for a second series.

> **Teenager Summer Farley (Sophie Stuckey) moves to Transylvania with her father and brother. She then starts at her new high school, Stoker High, which is filled with zombies, werewolves, vampires, mummies and many other sorts of monsters.** She tries to get through school with help from her friends, **Heidi the zombie** (Amy Wren) and **Bobby the werewolf** (Kane Ricca).

The series is from the correct time period and the Wikipedia plot summary mentions a teenage girl and her brother attending a high school filled with monsters, including a zombie and a werewolf.

According to the episodes list, episode 9 also features a brain in a jar.

> Summer and her friends want to go to the Cemetery Slam concert, and Bobby got tickets. However, her father, Doctor Farley grounds her and says she cannot go to the concert, due to irresponsible behavior. Summer tries everything to persuade him otherwise and then, accidentally, Doctor Farley ends up swapping bodies with **Leo, the brain in the jar.** Summer uses this to her advantage but then she accidentally ends up swapping bodies with the brain, causing her dad to end up in her body and Leo, still in her dad's. Mahem starts as they try to get back into their own bodies and Summer tries to convince her dad to let her go to the concert.

The brain in a jar is briefly visible at around the 0:36 mark in the trailer below.